# Power consumption in voltage multipliers

Tags: high-voltage

Cockcroft–Walton generators and Marx generators are voltage multipliers. These circuits contain various diodes, capacitors and resistors that charge the capacitors in parallel and then put them in series to multiply the voltage. How much do these circuits consume?

I saw videos on youtube that create 180kV sparks using a 9V battery.

EDITED: here's schematic Cockcroft–Walton generator:
[image]

Marx generator:
[image]

Comment: I think you should stick with one or the other because they are fundamentally different in operation. The Marx generator relies on spark gaps and will never work from a 9 volt battery for instance and, you specifically mention 9 volts in your words so, in effect, it is ruled out. And, on that note about the 9 volts, the CW generator shown runs from AC and not a battery.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry, the 9v battery is connected to a transformer, it's output is connected to the Cockcroft–Walton generator with 8kV output and this is connected to the Marx generator with 180 kV output https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8CVdFIVjPA&feature=emb_title&ab_channel=inductivecapacitor

Comment: You shouldn't connect batteries to transformers; they are incompatible. You can use a battery to power an oscillator that you can then connect to a transformer - is that what you mean. However, I think the point is being missed here; the two generators work on entirely different principles and expecting both circuits to be explained in one post is probably asking too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to realize is that the output voltage can be very high, but the output current is usually **very** low.

High voltage doesn't mean that you get a lot of power out of them.

They don't "consume" much power at all.  A typical Cockcroft-Walton multiplier may put out only a few milliamperes at several thousand volts.

Say you have a Cockcroft-Walton multiplier that puts out 3000VDC at 10 milliamperes.  You will have to supply (3000V* 0.01A = 30W) at the low voltage side.

You wouldn't normally need that much current, though.

You want the high voltage to drive a Marx generator.

A Marx generator slowly charges its capacitors through the resistors.  When the voltage gets high enough, the capacitors discharge through the spark gaps.  All of the energy is released at once, then the process starts again.

More current means a faster recharge of the capacitors in the Marx generator - less current just means that you get individual discharges (or discharges at longer intervals) rather than a constant "buzz" of Marx discharges.

Since you saw an example of a 9 volt battery driving the whole thing, it can't be really consuming much power - 9 volt batteries don't "do" high power.  If you push one really hard, you might get a couple of hundred milliampers out of it - at nine volts, maybe a couple of watts for a little while.

Your examples don't match what you would have seen in the videos, though.

The Marx generator shown would need about 45000 volts DC input to get to 180000 volts output.

The Cockcroft-Walton multiplier shown has a DC output far too low to drive the shown Marx generator to 180000 volts.